# Leaflet geojson unstable layer order

Tags: leaflet

I have a situation with Leaflet, where I want to display different layers on a map and toggle between them using a layer controller.

My problem is that one of the layer is a [geojson](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson) and I need to display the layers of that geojson in a specific order.

I do so using `bringToFront` and `bringToback` functions on the geojson layer.

But when I toggle between different layers using the controller, the ordering is lost.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ye0k8am4/) showing the problem. Toggle the layers and the triangle will change color.

Question : is there a way to keep the layers order stable while toggling around ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve the desired result, just by re-ordering your features in your geojson, without using Leaflet's `bringToBack()` method.

Higher position of an item in `geojson.features` array will result in higher display (above feaures with lower position).

The following function changes the order accordingly.

```
const moveLayersToBottom = (geojson, featureName) => {
  geojson.features.sort((x, y) => (
    x.properties.name === featureName ? -1 : y.properties.name === featureName ? 1 : 0
  ))
}

moveLayersToBottom(myGeojson, 'zone_1');
```

Here is your fiddle, edited (I commented out code of your fiddle that is unnecessary): https://jsfiddle.net/br0g962p/